# ios - Custom Parse Sever on Heroku and MongoLab error 3080 : JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: ios, json, heroku, parse-server

I am facing an error with mongoLab, Heroku and deploying a parse server.

I followed this blog post : https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/2/4/running-parse-on-heroku

I  visited Github, clicked the deploy button and then deployed my app to Heroku.

Next I installed parse using cocoa pods and then set my app keys **to the same ones** as my app deployed on Heroku like so:

[image]
​
Then, I wanted to test it out so I created a quick object and attempted to save it:

[image]
​
Then, I tried running my app and I get an error in the console:

[image]
​
Why is this happening? How can I fix this error? I am really lost because it appears I did everything right...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! This was so stupid!

All I had to do was make sure my url included the mount

[image]

So it was my `original_url/parse` that got replaced in my sever url in my app delegate!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that I had an @symbol in the password and I had not url-encoded it. When I escaped the symbol it started working.